# How to get related data with a ViewModel and limit the results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity, viewmodel

I'm not 100% sure how to word the question here so bear with me as I explain the situtaion and the problem.

I want to show a list of vessels (in a KendoUI Grid), each of those vessels can have many fixtures against them and those fixtures can have many periods.  I only need to show the single most recent fixture data for each vessel.

I attempted to do this but I ended up retruning no data at all, perhaps someone can help me out.  Here is my source code for this project, to start here are the table classes.

Table : Vessels

```
public partial class vessels
{

    public int vessel_id { get; set; }        
    public string vessel_name { get; set; }       

    public virtual ICollection<vessel_fixtures> vessel_fixtures { get; set; }        
}
```

Table : Vessel Fixtures

```
public partial class vessel_fixtures
{

    public int fixture_id { get; set; }
    public int vessel_id { get; set; }
    public string fixture_location { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<vessel_fixture_periods> vessel_fixture_periods { get; set; }
}
```

Table : Vessel Fixture Periods

```
public partial class vessel_fixture_periods
{

    public int period_id { get; set; }
    public int fixture_id { get; set; }
    public decimal day_rate { get; set; }

    public virtual vessel_fixtures vessel_fixtures { get; set; }        
}
```

To summarise their relationship.  One vessel can have many fixtures and one fixture can have many periods.

I created this viewmodel and enter the data I want to show.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MyProject.Models;

namespace MyProject.ViewModels
{
public class RelatedModel
    {

    // Vessels
    public int vessel_id { get; set; }
    public string vessel_name { get; set; }        

    // Fixtures
    public int fixture_id { get; set; }
    public int vessel_id { get; set; }        
    public string fixture_location { get; set; }

    // Fixture Periods
    public int period_id { get; set; }
    public int fixture_id { get; set; }
    public decimal day_rate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then wrote this method that the KendoUIO Grid can call to select the data and return as json.

```
public ActionResult vessels_read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var context = db.tbl_vessels.AsQueryable();

        IQueryable<RelatedModel> brokerspot = from o in context
                                              select new RelatedModel {
                                                      vessel_id = o.vessel_idx,
                                                      vessel_name = o.vessel_name
                                                      day_rate = o.vessel_fixture_periods.FirstOrDefault().day_rate
                                                      // ... omitted for brevity ... 

                                                  };
        DataSourceResult result = brokerspot.ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result);
```

This is where I am stuck however, this code only works if I remove the day_rate which I listed as FirstOrDefault thinking that it would allow me to return only the most recent period day rate.

For reference here is the kendoui grid code.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.ViewModels.RelatedModel>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
         {
             columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_id).Title("ID");
             columns.Bound(c => c.vessel_name).Title("Vessel");
             columns.Bound(c => c.day_rate).Title("Rate");

         })
         .Pageable()
         .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
             .Ajax()          
             .PageSize(40)
             .Model(model => 
                 {
                   model.Id(p => p.vessel_idx);
                 })
             .Read(read => read.Action("vessels_read", "Test"))                         
         ))
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Not totally understand you problem. But...
Should not there be a ',' at the end of vessel_name = o.vessel_name and before the day_rate ??

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, query returns collection of anonymous objects with vessel and `First` fixture period.

```
var results = vesselslist.Select(v=> new 
                           {
                               vessel=v, 
                               recent_period = v.vessel_fixtures.SelectMany(f=>f.vessel_fixture_periods)
                                                                .FirstOrDefault() // I used first, but place logic to pick recent.
                           });
```